# React Jest Test Warning When More Than 1 Test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am getting a weird warning when I use more than 1 test.
When I use this test.

```
  it("should render default values", () => {
    render(
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          userAuth: {
            profileId: 1,
            currentOrgId: 1,
            currentPrivileges: {}
          }
        }}
      >
        <SocialPostEdit
          id={elementId}
          socialPost={postContent}
          name={elementName}
        />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  });
```

I get no warnings. When I duplicate it. Like this

```
 it("should render default values", () => {
    render(
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          userAuth: {
            profileId: 1,
            currentOrgId: 1,
            currentPrivileges: {}
          }
        }}
      >
        <SocialPostEdit
          id={elementId}
          socialPost={postContent}
          name={elementName}
        />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  });
 it("should render default values 1", () => {
    render(
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          userAuth: {
            profileId: 1,
            currentOrgId: 1,
            currentPrivileges: {}
          }
        }}
      >
        <SocialPostEdit
          id={elementId}
          socialPost={postContent}
          name={elementName}
        />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  });
```

I get this error

```
 Warning: An update to SocialPostForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

The weird thing is why if I keep 1 test it works and if I add more than 1 it gives me warning?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, you need to wrap calls to render in [`act()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) as the documentation calls out:

```
 import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

 it("should render default values 1", () => {
    act(() => {
      render(
        <UserContext.Provider
          value={{
            userAuth: {
              profileId: 1,
              currentOrgId: 1,
              currentPrivileges: {}
            }
          }}
        >
          <SocialPostEdit
            id={elementId}
            socialPost={postContent}
            name={elementName}
          />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      );
    });
  });
```

Comment: Same Error When I Add it. Also why with one tests I don't get any warnings.

Comment: Every call to `ReactDOM.render` needs to be wrapped in `act`. Did you do it for all of your tests?

Comment: Yeah. When I put the same test twice I get that warning. Both tests with act. I am not getting why on two tests it produces that warning. Should I cleanup then render tree?

Comment: Can you paste more of your code? What did you change, and what does it look like now?